# my jquery function doesn't while selecting check box work in my page in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i am using  codeigniter and i have a check box and jquery function this work fine in custom php but in codeigniter it doesn't work, please solve the issue for me. The check box is given here.

Here my HTML :

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="progress" id="progress" value="In Progress">In Progress
 </label>
```

and here my jQuery function :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#progress').click(function () { 
        $('#datetimepicker9').val('');
        if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            alert('checked');
            $('#datetimepicker9').val('In Progress');
            $("#datetimepicker9").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#total_marks").prop("required", false);
            $("#obtain_marks").prop("required", false);
        } else if ($(this).prop("checked") == false) {
            $("#datetimepicker9").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#total_marks").prop("required", true);
            $("#obtain_marks").prop("required", true);
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: your question lacks of code, but what i think that could be happening is that you are registering an event to an element that is not yet in the document, this is just an assumption that the element is being lazy loaded3

Comment: Your problem is you do not have enough HTML :)

Comment: The 2nd thing I would do after going "Goodness it doesn't work" would be to view the generated HTML from the working Vanilla(Custom) PHP against what is being produced by your Codeigniter version and play spot the difference.